# *ngFor was working before I added bootstrap, and now everything is broken

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Property binding `ngForOf` not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the `"@NgModule.declarations"`

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="post-preview">
<h1 (click)="goToPost(post)" class="post-title">{{post.title}}</h1>
<p class="post-description">{{post.description}}</p>  </div>
```

everything was working fine before I added styling with bootstrap using

```
npm i -s bootstrap
```

Comment: what is the error u get ?

Comment: Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template ...

Comment: then probably u are using ngForOf somewhere in some module were u didn't add imports: [CommonModule] and u don't need to import CommonModule in app.module.ts the BrowserModule already containing CommonModule !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after addition of bootstrap; I added `imports: [CommonModule, ...],` to my home module and things working again.
before addition of bootstrap, i just imported `CommonModule` in `app.module.ts`